# Delete in MySql

Tags: mysql

I try to delete from a table in mysql but it doesn't allow me. 
I run:

```
delete from mytable where sourceid=2;
```

and I get:

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'mydatabase.history_mytable' doesn't exist
```

What is wrong here ? I think there should be an option to configure mysql in order not to check for this history table.

Comment: Sounds like there is a trigger running when you delete.  You'll have to investigate the `mydatabase` database schema to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Or, if you are running it from some kind of framework, there might be a table prefix defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this command:

```
Show triggers like "%mytable%"
```

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-triggers.html

And then if some trigger exists,

```
Drop trigger if exists mytable.[trigger_name]
```

Source : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/drop-trigger.html

if you don't use the trigger.

Comment: Thank you! it was a trigger defined.

Answer (score 1):

run the command

```
explain delete from ...
```

then you will see what the database does.